# Testkit / GradleRunner: How to use a proxy?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, testkit

For regular gradle actions, I have a `gradle.properties` file in my project or home which configures the proxy details (host/port etc.)

When using `GradleRunner`, the `gradle.properties` file is ignored by intention:
*"Any configuration in the default Gradle user home directory (e.g. ~/.gradle/gradle.properties) is not used for test execution. The TestKit does not expose a mechanism for fine grained control of all aspects of the environment (e.g., JDK). Future versions of the TestKit will provide improved configuration options."*

(from https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#sec:controlling_the_build_environment)

**Question:**
How can I configure a proxy when using `GradleRunner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a `gradle.properties` file with the proxy settings to your test project (run with `GradleRunner`). Here’s a complete example project (Gradle 7.1 Wrapper files not shown):

```
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── test
        └── groovy
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── MyTest.groovy
```

### `build.gradle`

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-groovy-3.0')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

### `src/test/groovy/com/example/MyTest.groovy`

```groovy
package com.example

import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner
import static org.gradle.testkit.runner.TaskOutcome.*
import spock.lang.TempDir
import spock.lang.Timeout
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTest extends Specification {

    @TempDir File projDir

    @Timeout(10)
    def "network connection through proxy works"() {
        given:
        def myTestTask = 'foo'
        new File(projDir, 'settings.gradle') << "rootProject.name = 'my-test'"
        new File(projDir, 'gradle.properties') << '''\
            systemProp.http.proxyHost = 192.168.123.123
            '''
        new File(projDir, 'build.gradle') << """\
            task $myTestTask {
                doLast {
                    println(new java.net.URL('http://www.example.com').text)
                }
            }
            """

        when:
        def result = GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(projDir)
            .withArguments(myTestTask)
            .build()

        then:
        result.task(":$myTestTask").outcome == SUCCESS
    }
}
```

I’ve used a non-existing dummy proxy which leads to a test failure because of a test/connection timeout (→ `SpockTimeoutError`). Using a real proxy instead, the test should succeed.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried and it does not work in my case. Please clone `https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin.git`, put your `gradle.properties` into the project home and run the `check` task. In my case, I get a `[repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.12.215] failed: connect timed out`error (use the `-i` switch) - maybe somethings wrong in that project - but at least here, my proxy settings seems to be ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by “project home”? Do you mean the project root directory (i.e., the base directory of the Git clone)? How would that be related to the question on how to use a proxy in a test project run with `GradleRunner`?

Comment: Thanks for asking those questions :) I did not realize that a GradleRunner builds its own isolated environment with its own project directory, often a temporary directory. I will have a look and adjust my sources according to your examples.